# Alternating bullet notes styled with images

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

I'm currently trying to alternate the colors of my bullet notes using some images.
However, I encountered several problems:

1. If I press backspace to delete one of the bullets, there's a blue line from contenteditable that appears - try backspacing everything in the fiddle link I gave and you'll see what I mean. There's probably an easy fix for this by making the border 0px, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax
2. The main problem is that I want it written in a way so that when the user presses enter, the next color bullet, or image in this case, will show up. I don't want it to show up all at once, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I'm assuming either CSS classes or Javascript is involved - I'm kind of new to these languages.

This is a snippet from the whole code that needs fixing:

```
<body>
    <div contenteditable>
        <div id = "notes"
            <ul>
                <li style =  "list-style-image: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2nb9jxs.png')">Click here to edit</li>
                <li style = "list-style-image: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2m5xb1f.png')"> Click here </li>
                <li style = "list-style-image: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/2qb5342.png')"> Click here </li>
            </ul>
            <style>
                #notes { 
                    position: absolute;
            </style>
        </div>
    </div
</body
```

And here's the fiddle.js link: http://jsfiddle.net/95Wvv/
It would be nice if you gave a solution in fiddle as well. Thank you!

Comment: why is your `<style></style>` tags hanging in the middle of the `<body></body>`. `<style></style>` should be located in `<head></head>`

Comment: Sorry, I learned HTML along with everything else a few days ago. I'll change it in my actual code. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Sorry for being a bit rude, there was too many errors for me. Don't forget to close every tag (well, everything), or it will result by unexpected errors. A clean and valid HTML markup avoid you to loose time searching for errors which should have never exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edited to fit OP requirements*

- Move your `contenteditable` on `<ul>`
- Add `outline: 0` to your `<li>`

HTML :

```
<div>
    <div id="notes">       
        <ul contenteditable>
            <li style="list-style-image: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2nb9jxs.png')">Click here to edit</li>
            <li style="list-style-image: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2m5xb1f.png')"> Click here </li>
            <li style="list-style-image: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/2qb5342.png')"> Click here </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#notes { 
    position: absolute;
}
[contenteditable] {
    outline: none;
}
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/95Wvv/5/)**

---

**EDIT**

To alternate colors, use this code :

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="notes">       
        <ul contenteditable>
            <li>Click here to edit</li>
            <li>Click here </li>
            <li>Click here </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#notes { 
    position: absolute;
}
[contenteditable] {
    outline: none;
}
li {
    list-style-image: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2nb9jxs.png');
}
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    list-style-image: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2m5xb1f.png');
}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    list-style-image: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2qb5342.png');
}
```

[**Another JSFiddle !**](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/95Wvv/6/)

Comment: It seems like with your solution, I can't press enter more than once per bullet. But I don't quite understand why it restricts me

Comment: Ow ok, I understand what you're trying to do. Try to remove `contenteditable` attribute from every `<li>`, and add it to `<ul>`. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/95Wvv/5/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll set your thing to the solution. Can you give me any tips on my second problem though?

Comment: OOPS. I think I didn't refresh the page. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix part one, add `outline: 0;` to the Element that has `contenteditable` on it (http://jsfiddle.net/95Wvv/)